# Como le hago para obtener un valor especifico de un elemento al momento de crearlo SQL y Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, tkinter

```
def CreateCRUD():
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usuarios")
    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
    
    datos=[
        miNombre.get(),     miApellido.get(),
        miDireccion.get(),  miPass.get(),
        textoComentario.get(0.0, "end")
    ]
    
    try:
        miCursor.execute("""INSERT INTO DATOSUSUARIOS(NOMBRE_USUARIO,APELLIDO,DIRECCION,PASSWORD,COMENTARIOS)
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""", datos)
        miConexion.commit()
        #-----------------------ESTE ES EL PROBLEMA------------------------
        miCursor.execute("""SELECT ID FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE 
        NOMBRE_USUARIO=?, APELLIDO=?, DIRECCION=?,
        PASSWORD=?, COMENTARIOS=?""", datos)
        #--------------------AQUI TERMINA
        obteniendoId=miCursor.fetchall()
        miIdComprobado=obteniendoId[0][0]
        print(miIdComprobado)
        
        messagebox.showinfo("BBDD","Registro insertado exitosamente")
        messagebox.showinfo("BBDD","Tu ID es:"+ miIdComprobado)
    
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("ATENCION", "no se a podido insertar el registro")

    miConexion.close()
```

Quiero hacer que se busque el ID, que este se guarde en una variable y que luego este se le entregue y diga al usuario de forma que este lo recuerde para luego utilizarlo

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que le pasa al código que has puesto?¿Da algún error?¿Qué versión de python y qué conector mysql usas?

Comment: El tag dice MySQL pero la conexión es `miConexion=sqlite3.connect(...)`. ¿Es MySql o SQLite?

Comment: estoy utilizando SQLite3

Answer (score 2):

podrias utilizar la funcion **lastrowid**, recuerda que esta es por cada cursor, ya que te devuelve el id de la ultima fila insertada a traves de ese cursor.

```py
    def CreateCRUD():
        miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Usuarios")
        miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
        
        datos=[
            miNombre.get(),     miApellido.get(),
            miDireccion.get(),  miPass.get(),
            textoComentario.get(0.0, "end")
        ]
        
        try:
            miCursor.execute("""INSERT INTO DATOSUSUARIOS(NOMBRE_USUARIO,APELLIDO,DIRECCION,PASSWORD,COMENTARIOS) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""", datos)
            obteniendoId = miCursor.lastrowid
            miConexion.commit()
            miIdComprobado="Tu ID es: {}".format(obteniendoId) 
            messagebox.showinfo("BBDD","Registro insertado exitosamente")
            messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", miIdComprobado)
        except:
            messagebox.showwarning("ATENCION", "no se a podido insertar el registro")
    
        miConexion.close()
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudaste muchisimo solo que le tube que agregar unas cositas por que me saltaba un error en 
messagebox.showinfo("BBDD","Tu ID es:"+ miIdComprobado)

asi que agregue una linea y cambie un par de cositas
miCursor.execute("""INSERT INTO DATOSUSUARIOS(NOMBRE_USUARIO,APELLIDO,DIRECCION,PASSWORD,COMENTARIOS) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""", datos)

obteniendoId = miCursor.lastrowid
miIdComprobado="Tu ID es: {}".format(obteniendoId)
messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", miIdComprobado)

Comment: Ya agregue lo que comentas, para tener una idea clara de como te funciono